# Home Page is not open in browser

Tags: asp.net, xml

Create Default.aspx in the asp.net;

And open folder in windows.

Right-Click on Default.aspx then OpenWidth and click on the Internet Explorer.

when Opend. view:



"

The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'file:///G:/My Programming/Asp/My Project (90)/Defa...

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
-^

"

Comment: You need a webserver to serve an asp.net page (iis + asp.net, apache + mono)

Answer (score 0):

.aspx page are ASP.NET server side pages means they get rendered on the Server and return result back to webbrowser

So you cannot call them by directory path you will need to host them on a webserver and then call them by the wepath e.g. localhost/test.aspx

Please read the walkthrough it will give information on everything you need for ASPX http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.90).aspx